# Taking only one command line argument in putty using c

Tags: c, arguments

Hi i want to make code that accepts only one input file by c.
For example i want input file's name that is shortinput.txt !
so I will take one command line argument at putty and I also want to make the code get only one argument. If the number of command-line arguments is not 1 (zero or more than 1), then should
print a usage string on the display and exit the program. The usage string looks like this:
usage: ./hw2 input_filename

The problem is here. In the code below I want to print error not only the argument is empty but more than one!

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 if(argv[1]==NULL||argv[2]||argv[3])//where i want to fix  
 {
     printf("usage: ./hw2 input_filename"); 
 }  
 FILE *fp =fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
 if(fp==NULL){
     printf("The input file does not exist.\n"); 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: That's what `argc` is for. It tells you how many args there are (including the executable name).

Comment: if there are 3 arguments then argv[3] won't be null. So, what is the problem?

Comment: you are trying to access `argv[1]` ,`argv[2]` and `argv[3]` which might get you segmentation fault if arguments are less. first check `argc` value and then only access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check how many arguments were passed. You have `argc` parameter for that.

```
if(argc != 2)
{
    printf("usage: ./hw2 input_filename");
    /* do more (exit etc) */
}
```

Comment: @Lundin possible... But he can ask user to input one as well